# how to make sidebar or top bar that wont disappear when i navigate to the other page?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

The sidebar disappear when navigating other pages. I am planning to make project about admin page. Do I need to include every pages?

Comment: edit your question and add your code of admin page.

Answer (score 0):

There are many kind of web application, one of them is Single page application, where website or app contains all its content within a single page example Gmail, Facebook etc.

In contrast, multi-page websites typically load completely new pages in response to user action.

If you are loading different page with every action, then Yes you have to add sidebar to every page itself.

Both may require different tools and technologies to a certain extent, which you should see before proceeding.